# Execute .bat on remote server

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I have a server and a pc connected to the server.

In the server I've got a .bat file wich does some rutines.

On the pc I use this:

```
psexec \\IPServer -U User -P Pass -s cmd.exe
```

So, when I execute this, I can use the consele and then execute the .bat stored on the server.

In the command line:

```
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\update.bat
```

I would like to know if there is any option to do this in one step, I mean, to connect to the server, run cmd and execute the .bat in one line.

Is this possible?

Hope you undestand me, English is not my first language.

Kind regards

Comment: As in, `psexec ... cmd.exe /c C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\update.bat`?

Comment: I would have thought just giving it the path to the bat file would be enough.  The file association would tell the system to run it with cmd.exe.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: @Squashman thank you very much, it worked perfect!!

Comment: `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create c:\\windows\\notepad` is the windows way to run commands. See `wmic /?` and `wmic process call /?`.

Comment: An easy way is also PowerShell `Invoke-Command`.